# Why does Joomla have both models and tables?

Tags: mvc, model, jtable, jmodel

In classic MVC, you have models that loosely corresponds to the underlying database tables. Why would Joomla need both models and tables?

**Edit**

Some quotes from provided links:

> In summary, the model focuses on business logic and the table on data entities in the database.  By entity, I mean a single row in a table in a database.
>
> "So, a JModel class would have one, or more, JTable classes as properties?"
>
> That is the idea.

Comment: Are you referring to the `JTable` class?

Comment: @Lodder Yes, JTable and JModel classes.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=163897) and [this](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=163897) may help

Comment: I believe there is no real reason for this. Just some Joomla legacy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class `JTable` is created to work strictly on database object. Table object should create,modify,delete,check data in database. It can be used in many models, helpers, modules. Single model some times have to use multiple tables and it can happen in many models. If you use `JTable` you don't have to rewrite SQL in every model just to retrieve or modify a single table record. Not to mention that changes in a `JTable` work in every place where table was used.

Class `JModel` is created to work on data. Usually it works on database data but also files, images or simply calculations. Models don't require a `JTable`, you can easly write a working `JModel` without it. But when you have to create for example a user account on a complex portal it is possible user data will consist not only of a single table but also example data or records in other tables. Using `JTable` will allow you to save time on writing CRUD methods and make sure that in every place a single table is used SQL will always be up-to-date.

Having those two separated allows developer to create various extensions that are not tied strictly to database. For example gallery that in model will not only work on database object but also images. Developer does write image processing code and leaves SQL for creating and updating database to `JTable`.

It can be a bit confusing at the beginning but after few extension you'll see that it is actually helpful. The bigger the extension the more time `JTable`+`JModel` will save for developer. The only problem is that it isn't properly explained in documentation.

#### Here are some useful links

- [Using the JTable class](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_JTable_class)

Comment: But that should be part of an object hierarchy, not two different classes.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Table can be used in many places. If you merge model and table you have to use a complete model or write SQL for simple get methods in for example modules and plugins. Framework have to be versatile. Creating SQL in every place where you want to use same table is a waste. When you update the JTable it is updated in every place you use it. You don't have to rewrite it. Not to mention that no one requires from you to use `JTable`. You can write extensions without it and they will work as intended. But try to build something bigger. You will see how helpful `JTable`it is.